# Issues in getting the text field while selecting the radio button

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys i have written a code in HTML in which i have two radio button in that i have added a functionality that if i select the second radio button then only the text field show 
**HTML:**

```
<strong>Location Type:</strong>
<input type="radio" name="target" value= "BrowserDownload" checked >BrowseLocal
<input type="radio" name="target" value="dumpToS3"  > S3Remote 

<br/>


<div id="textboxes" style="display: none">
  <strong>ACCESS_KEY_ID: </strong>
  <input class="box"  type="text"  hidden="true"/ > <br/>
  <strong>ACCESS_SECRET_KEY: </strong>
  <input  class="box" type="text" hidden="true"/> <br/>
  <strong>MAIL: </strong>
  <input  class="box" type="text"  hidden="true"/> <br/>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("input[name='target']").on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val() == "dumpToS3")
       $('#textboxes').show('slow');
    else
        $('#textboxes').hide();
});
```

**Please Go on this site for live DEMO:**http://jsfiddle.net/Vk24X/254/
In this when i click on second radio button it should show both the name and text field but its only showing names for the text field please tell me where i'm doing wrong..thnx in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vk24X/260/ updated the fiddle. Remove the `hidden="true"`

Comment: Remove hidden = "true" , Even display:none is not needed

Answer (score 2):

remove [`hidden="true"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) from your textboxes and it should work.

your [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vk24X/259/)

Comment: thnx for the help

Comment: I have one question i want to fill that text field with some text so i want to call it to my python program with code : "Consume= request.form.get('textboxes')" to get that mail and access key in my code is it work?

Comment: If you fill the textbox you will get it on backend if your textbox is inside form

Comment: ya it is inside form this code "Consume= request.form.get('textboxes')" is correct right? we can call it with ID

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Comment: I need to ask one more thing that just suppose i have  two function in my python program one for "ACCESS_KEY_ID" and "ACCESS_KEY_ID" and one for "MAIL" so should i have to call it from different ID name from UI to python or same ID that is "textboxes" is ok? cause i'm providing some values from UI which is hard coded in my code i'm sure it will work

Comment: @rahulsingh you need to ask different question for this, one question you post should be limited to specific problem.

Comment: yea i got it but i was asking a simple thing for that asking a full question is not good for this Consume= request.form.get('textboxes') i'm getting None i'm not sure why its not containing anything

Comment: @rahulsingh you do not have form tag in your html, google it for demos

Answer (score 1):

Remove `hidden="true"` from your `input` tag.

```js
$("input[name='target']").on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val() == "dumpToS3")
       $('#textboxes').show('slow');
    else
        $('#textboxes').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Location Type:</strong>
<input type="radio" name="target" value= "BrowserDownload" checked >BrowseLocal
<input type="radio" name="target" value="dumpToS3"  > S3Remote 

<br/>

<!-- <div> -->
<div id="textboxes" style="display: none">
  <strong>ACCESS_KEY_ID: </strong>
  <input class="box"  type="text" / > <br/>
  <strong>ACCESS_SECRET_KEY: </strong>
  <input  class="box" type="text" /> <br/>
  <strong>MAIL: </strong>
  <input  class="box" type="text"  /> <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: thnx for the help